# Finding Maximum in a series of tables

Tags: list-manipulation

I have written a piece of Mathematica code, where I have imported 4 data sets of x, y variables into 4 tables under a variable psi. I have plotted 4 different graphs of them on the same frame and would now like to find the x values of maximum y values of those 4 graphs, could someone guide me how to do this, that is extract the maxima of set 1 then set2 and so on. Finally taking their average.

Comment: Show us your data and current code, otherwise we can't give you specific help. Generally speaking, you will be interested in `Interpolation`, and `FindMaximum` or `NMaximize`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. In its current form, your question is hard to answer without having a specific example. If you would consider including a [small, self-contained code-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question, chances are much better that someone can help you with your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example with made-up data:

```
(* make up some data to resemble yours *)
psi = Transpose@Table[{x, Sin[x - n/3] - n/2}, {x, -1, 2, 3/10}, {n, -1, -3, -1}];

ListLinePlot@psi
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now construct interpolations of each data set, then find maxima for those:

```
interpolated = Interpolation /@ psi
NMaximize[#[x], x] & /@ interpolated

(* Out: {{1.49981, {x -> 1.23723}},
         {1.99983, {x -> 0.903279}}, 
         {2.49987, {x -> 0.569387}}} *)
```

Comment: psi = Table[Import[( "data" ) <> ToString[k] <> ".dat"], {k, 1, 4}];

#here I have 4 data sets imported called data1.dat, data2.dat ....

    ListPlot[Table[psi[[i]], {i, 1, 5}], PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 700, Axes -> False, Frame -> True]

Graph plotted using above code.

All my data sets are of the form {x,y}, I can call the entire data set with psi[[i]] but don't know how to pull out x for maximum y in a particular psi[[i]] data set. Thanks. @MarcoB

Comment: @user142756 Can you not apply the technique I showed in the answer to your data? Where do you get stuck? Notice that you still have not provided *the actual data*, so again I can do no more than just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code and it worked:

`Part[MaximalBy[Last] /@ psi, All, 1, 1]`

Thanks for your help.